# Publish a Gazebo message into a ROS topic?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I've been following this toturial (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=guided_i1) to create a pulgin in Gazebo and to be able to control it with ROS. Now i would like to publish the sensor scan data (that i think is only available as a Gazebo message ) into a ROS node. It is posible to edit this plugin to add this functionality?Is there any tutorial/resource/code explained that I can take a look to understand how it works?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18881/publish-a-gazebo-message-into-a-ros-topic?/) by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 68 on 2018-04-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It is definitely possible to edit the plugin you already have. Another option is to use an already existing plugin in the gazebo_ros_pkgs library that publishes your laser data to a ROS topic. The plugin you are looking for is **libgazebo_ros_laser.so**. You can find the source code from here:

```
http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/gazebo_plugins/html/gazebo__ros__laser_8cpp_source.html
```

So you have two options here:

1. Modify your existing plugin to also have the functionality of advertising the laser scan data to a ROS topic by using the given source code as a reference.
2. Adding the existing gazebo_ros_laser plugin to your SDF file like so:

   0 0 -0.004645 1.5707 0 0
      true
      30
      
        
          
            32
            1
            -0.53529248
            0.18622663
          
        
        
          0.05
          70
          0.02
        
      
      
        /your/sensor/topic/name
        /your/frame/name

Notice the plugin tag at the end of the sensor tag. The libgazebo_ros_laser come inside the gazebo_ros_pkgs package which you probably already have installed.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-04-02**:
Thanks for answering!

I've been trying to solve it in the easy way, and its not working for me. I add the "libgazebo_ros_laser.so" , and set the topic and framename, but i can´t see the rostopic. And I think that the problem is that Gazebo doesn't even try to load the plugin, because no matter what I write in the "filename" field, I don't get an error  which is weird. Any idea why this happends?

Anyway, the code of the plugin is being useful and maybe I can adapt my own gazebo plugi

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-04-02**:
Can you launch Gazebo with --verbose option to possibly see more error messages?

**Comment by [Mansan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4773/mansan/) on 2018-04-02**:
Ok, I get the error message(gazebo cannot find the plugin).But I've tried with rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo, and when I add my model I can see the laserscan topic. The only thing is ,that I cannot run the .world (so the model doesn,t rotate ) but I think that it can be solved creating a launch file with my .world file, and then using roslaunch.

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-04-03**:
To run a .world file you can just do rosrun gazebo gazebo_ros your.world. But you're right you can also use a .launch file for this.